# WPF window in front of Taskbar (using dual monitor), how can I do it?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a dual monitor app. So, i reach this goal with the following code:

```
var myWindow = new MyWindow();

var workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[selectedMonitor].WorkingArea;
myWindow.Top = workingArea.Top;
myWindow.Left = workingArea.Left;
myWindow.Height = workingArea.Height;
myWindow.Width = workingArea.Width;
myWindow.Show();
```

If i pass to `selectedMonitor` the value 1, the app is opened in the second monitor, everything is ok, but when i pass the value 0, the app is opened in the first monitor, but the windows taskbar is in front of the app.

How can i put the `myWindow` in front of taskbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `WindowStyle` to `None` (so it doesn't have a border) and set the `WindowState` to `Maximized` or set the sizing manually, it'll be in front of the taskbar. If you want the titlebar and whatnot, I'm not sure what you can do.

Additionally, [`WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea) doesn't include the area over the titlebar. The docs specifically say it excludes that. So you don't want that either. You probably just want the [`Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds).

Comment: When i put WindowsState to Maximized the app only opens in the first monitor, independently the value of `selectedMonitor`.