# Window against of taskbar

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, window

I have a problem with my WPF window. I set the `TopMost="True"` to be forever on top. The problem is that when I click on another window (for example Firefox) my window remains on top, but in back of taskbar (Start bar), so the taskbar is in top, then my window, and then the Firefox window. I use Windows 7.

**Quesion: what I must to change in my code to set my window against of taskbar?**

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Pixeli morti" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#00000000" Topmost="True" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="canvas1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402570/wpf-window-in-front-of-taskbar-using-dual-monitor-how-can-i-do-it)

Comment: I saw it, but it didn't help me... Like in quesion I repeat: when I click on another window, the taskbar goes in top... Please help, if you can.

Comment: Does configuring the windows task bar to 'not topmost' work as a solution for you?

Comment: @John you can try this, get the taskbar handle FindWindow ("Shell_TrayWnd",NULL) and use the code from my answer below to set it to NoTopMost. But i advice you not to mess with the taskbar.

Comment: @downvoter, why? Add a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, no matter to what window you switch it will allways stays on top and over the taskbar.
I used the SetWindowPos method, included it via p/invoke.

To make that work, we need some enumerations and flags, be reminded that you propably don't need all of the flags, but its always a good idea to have a library with all the most used pinvoke methods.

```
public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
    SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,
    SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,
    SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,
    SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,
    SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
    SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,
    SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,
    SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,
    SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,
    SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,
    SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,
    SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,
    SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,
}
public static class HWND
{
   public static IntPtr
   NoTopMost = new IntPtr(-2),
   TopMost = new IntPtr(-1),
   Top = new IntPtr(0),
   Bottom = new IntPtr(1);
}
```

also you need the actual method, its a good idea to place that in a static helper class like WinApi for example

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);
```

and finally in the window code i called the method with the necessary parameters:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.SourceInitialized += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        WinApi.SetWindowPos(wih.Handle, HWND.TopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE);
    };
}
```

you might need to call that method again, if your window gets resized, minimized or maximized. In fact if it gets activated again. Also you should check how it behaves with Modal dialogs.

Comment: I integrated your code in my code. No errors. The problem is same: when I click on another window, my WPF window doesn't remain in top (in front of taskbar), but +1 for code. If you will can fix my problem, I will mark it. :)

Comment: @John well at one point you simply can't anymore make an deactivated window topmost. The taskbar and your window are now both topmost, and it would be a useability disaster if a deactivated window could still keep the topmost status. So microsoft decided to split the order into two groups(simply spoken). The "Normal" windows where the focus decides who goes on top and all topmost windows where the focus decides which topmost window is now topmost. There is no special method to make a window absolutely topmost.

Comment: Ok, thank you for feedback. But, how can http://join.me application maintain a topmost (in front of taskbar, too) orange rectangle?

Comment: I don't know the application, so i can just guess. Maybe they simply draw on the desktop, maybe its some sort of tooltip (which by the way needs to play well with topmost aswell), maybe they just hack it by calling SetWindowPos alot of the time or everytime the Z position is changed. Whatever it is, i wouldn't cosider it user friendly when it gets in my way of using the taskbar.